# builtin password reset view problem in django1.3

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi am absolutely new to django,Now I am tring for builtin **reset password view.**.
 I follow the link [link](http://ygamretuta.me/2011/02/08/django-1-2-auth-part-3-password-resets-and-changes/)
But I got the error when I click on reset password button at /password_reset/ : 

**error at /accounts/password_reset/**

```
[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\socket.py in create_connection, line 571


  'urls.py'
```

(r'^accounts/password_reset$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset','template_name':'user/password_reset_form.html','email_template_name':'user/password_reset_email.html'}),

(r'^accounts/password/reset/confirm/(?P[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13})-(?P[0-9Aa-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', **'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'**, {'template_name' : 'user/password_reset.html',  'post_reset_redirect': '/logout/' }),

```
     (r'^accounts/password_reset/done/$',<b>'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'</b>,{'template_name':'user/password_reset_done.html'}),


    (r'^accounts/change_password/$',<b> 'password_change'</b>, {'post_change_redirect' : '/accounts/change_password/done/'}),

    (r'^accounts/change_password/done/$',<b> 'password_change_done'</b>,{'template_name':'user/password_change_done.html'}),


<b>password_reset_email.html</b>


{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content%}
{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
{% endblock %}
```

I add necessary templates in the folder 'user'.
Please help me,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As rdegges said, it's a connection error. Check which port the request is trying to access, and make sure windows firewall is set up to receive on that port. You can check the port by looking through django's traceback page, and looking at the "local vars".

From the looks of it, it's an email port. Take another look at the traceback and look out for django trying to send a request to port 25. If it does, make sure your port 25 is configured to receive.

Also, you'll need a makeshift SMTP server for testing purposes because you probably wouldn't want to be using a real one. Just have this running in a separate command prompt window while you're running django, and any emails that django tries to send through your port 25 will be saved in an "emails" folder in the working directory.

```
#/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
import asyncore
from smtpd import SMTPServer

class EmlServer(SMTPServer):
    no = 0
    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        filename = '%s-%d.eml' % (datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'), self.no)
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
        print '%s saved.' % filename
        self.no += 1


def run():
    foo = EmlServer(('localhost', 25), None)
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from os.path import exists, join
    from os import mkdir, chdir, getcwd

    target_directory = join( getcwd(), "emails" )
    if exists(target_directory):
        chdir(target_directory)
    else:
        try:
            mkdir(target_directory)
        except OSError:
            from sys import exit
            exit("The containing folder couldn't be created, check your permissions.")
        chdir(target_directory)
    print "Using directory %s" % target_directory

    run()
```

Comment: how can I configure the port 25?

Comment: Go to your control panel and open "Windows Firewall". Then, click "Advanced Settings" and add a new inbound rule allowing traffic on port 25 (After verifying that it's port 25 that's causing the problem and not another one). Then, make sure your port 25 is properly configured on the network, just as you configured the port apache uses (probably 80)

Comment: Can I use development server (builtin  in django) for the purpose.am sorry to specify now am in development server

Comment: Your code sends a request back to your server's port 25 (be sure it's this port), so you'll need it set up if you want to test. I'll edit in a file for helping debug smtp requests. Just run this in the background and make sure traffic is allowed on port 25.

Comment: You'll also want to make sure django is making the request to "localhost:25", or a properly-configured "domain.com:25"

Comment: Thanks for your response.I run the prorgram,no mails created in the folder 'email'

Comment: After the daemon is running, start up the server. Then, try to change a password. The server, if my guess is right, tries to email a confirmation email to the username's respective email address. What this daemon will do is catch all those attempts and instead output the emails as .eml files in the "emails" directory

Comment: Would you still like help? I can go into detail, but I'll need more information on your setup

Answer (score -1):

The error you're getting is a connection error--that means that the server you're using to run your Django site is likely not working correctly. Here are some things you can try on your Django server:

- If you're running your Django site via `python manage.py runserver`, you can try to simply re-run that command.
- If you're running your site via a webserver like apache, try restarting apache.

If neither of those work, post a comment and let me know what operating system you're running your site on, and how you're running it, and we can do further debugging.

Comment: Am using Windows7,and run using python manage.py runserver.[now am in development server],Is it possible to send mail using the built in development server in Django?